# Tool suggestion for Database Testing

Tags: automated-testing, database

Anyone can suggest/recommand a automation tool which will cover DB testing end2end. 
The tool should support sql queries execution,Test Reports generation and support the CI/CD.

Comment: It would be better if you could write your own code, like using nodejs, java or python to connect to the database. This would much for easy to maintain and also will cover more scenarios than depending on a tool. It might have a huge learning curve initially but once the setup is achieved it would be fairly easier to maintain than having a specific tool.

Comment: Thank you for your response !,I am thinking same way ,but looking for any tools are available in market?

Comment: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/tools/40-best-database-testing-tools/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Best 10 Data base testing Tool:**

www.agiledata.org

```
1.Oracle SQL Developer 
2.Data Factory
3.Orion
4.MS SQL Server
5.NoSQLUNIT
6.Mockup Data  
7.DTM Data Generator
8.SQL Test
9.SeLite
10.SLOB
```